# Handler / Looper / send message to Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, android-looper

i wrote a test app to understand the comunication mechanism between Threads.

my sources :

> http://techtej.blogspot.de/2011/02/android-passing-data-between-main.html,
>   [send message to Thread which is listening for data from network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104481/send-message-to-thread-which-is-listening-for-data-from-network)

I don't understand how to use the Handler and the Looper.

> Here : (every step should give his state : Log.v(TAG, "..."))
>
> - MainActivity create and start Thread (Runnable "r")
> - MainActivity --> Message to --> r
> - MainActivity <-- modified Message <-- r

`package com.example.desktop.testhandlerlooper;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    private Handler mHandler2;
    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mHandler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Log.v(TAG, (String)msg.obj);
            }
        };

        mHandler.post(r);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        for(int i = 10; i>=0; i--)
        {
            Message msg = mHandler2.obtainMessage();
            msg.arg1 = 3;
            msg.obj = String.valueOf(i);
            mHandler2.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        private static final String TAG = "Thread";
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.v(TAG, "Before the looper");
            Looper.prepare();
            //=======================================
            mHandler2 = new Handler() {
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                       Message m = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                        //Message message = Message.obtain();
                        m.obj = "ACK:" + msg.obj;
                        Log.v(TAG, (String)m.obj);
                        //message.sendToTarget();

                        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                    }
                }
            };
            //=======================================
            Looper.loop();
            Log.v(TAG, "After the looper");
        }
    };
}`

Logcat :

> --------- beginning of crash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.desktop.testhandlerlooper, PID: 2872
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.desktop.testhandlerlooper/com.example.desktop.testhandlerlooper.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.os.Message android.os.Handler.obtainMessage()' on a null
>   object reference
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Message
>   android.os.Handler.obtainMessage()' on a null object reference
>                         at com.example.desktop.testhandlerlooper.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:35)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1237)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6253)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>   Application terminated.

Beside what i am trying to do, i understand the error but don't know how to fix it. Maybe Synchronization between both, MainThread and ChildTread ?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to use mHandler2 variable before initialization as you can see at log line at:
com.example.desktop.testhandlerlooper.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:35)

you should first declare and initialize variables and then start to use them.